# What is Xming and Xming-mesa

Tags: putty, xming

I'm trying to install Xming on Windows. How do I determine if I need Xming or Xming-mesa?  Both are listed at http://www.straightrunning.com/xmingnotes/.

Comment: Which client do you want to use?  Both to the same identical thing.. Both are the same client, one uses X Windows the other OpenGL, this is a personal choice, pick the one you want to use.

Comment: Just so you understand the reason I didn't find this question helpful.  You are seeking our opinion on which version of the client you should use.

Comment: I'm using putty. Does that narrow down my choice? Could you explain what the difference is?

Comment: I already did.  Both versions use putty.  Your choice is a cosmetic one.

Comment: Because I'm SSHing into a Linux box, does it not depend on the Linux machine I'm SSHing into?

Comment: Your choice is purely a cosmetic one.  Which one do you want to use?  Pick that one.

Comment: This is not useful in helping me to make an informed decision.

Comment: I have told you what the differences are between the two versions.  I have explained the choice is purely a cosmetic one.  I will not share you my opinion on the matter, questions seeking opinions, are strictly not on topic.  I have gone beyond the call of duty to explain one client uses OpenGL to draw its Windows the other uses the X-Windows framework.

Comment: I have very limited understanding of what OpenGL, X-Windows, mesa and such unfortunately. So are these software that is run on my Linux machine? Or that is run on my Windows machine when I get the Xming?

Comment: And does this have anything to do with GNOME or Unity?

Comment: @Ramhound: I'm pretty sure that the Win32 version of an X server does not use X-Windows for its own drawing, since that would need to be interpreted by another X server.  Could it be GDI vs OpenGL?

Comment: It probably is.  Horrible documentation.

Comment: @Ramhound: Looking again, it seems to affect what protocols are accepted by the server, and has nothing to do with the mechanism the server uses for its own drawing.

Answer (score 3):

Clients using X drawing calls alone will work with either server, while clients using OpenGL drawing calls need a server with X extensions for OpenGL.  That extension used to be provided by the special Xming-mesa version.

On the page you linked, you no longer even have a choice:

> OpenGL support is now provided by all Xming installers (Xming used to have separate builds and installers; with and without Mesa).

Comment: The download links point to different files though. Would you have any suggestions on what to read to understand this better? What you said doesn't register much, due to my lack of background knowledge.

Comment: @Tosh: Are you looking at the 8 year old downloads, which are an entire major version out of date?  The "now" in the above quote likely means "For version 7.x and later".

Comment: I see. It looks like a donation is required for version 7.x though.

Comment: The author of that website appears totally clueless about his GPL obligations.  Anyway, there are many free X servers available for windows, I usually use the cygwin/X ones myself.

Comment: @BenVoigt I don't know much about Xming but it seems to be mostly one man show, so he can relicense later versions to anything he wants. He's the owner of the new code. Now, if the old code base was infected by other contributers, that's another thing...